# Solution for dynamically chaning the query in react-apollo

Tags: reactjs, graphql-js, apollo, react-apollo, higher-order-components

`react-apollo` has an example in their [docs](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/queries.html#graphql-options) where they compute query variables based on a components props:

```
// The caller could do something like:
<ProfileWithData avatarSize={300} />

// And our HOC could look like:
const ProfileWithData = graphql(CurrentUserForLayout, {
  options: ({ avatarSize }) => ({ variables: { avatarSize } }),
})(Profile);
```

I have a use case where I'd like to change the ***query*** based on component props, but am little hard pressed figuring out how to do this.

To be more specific, I am trying to change the `CurrentUserForLayout` object that I am importing from another file.

Comment: Would a switch inside the resolver work? You can definitely compute results from props: http://dev.apollodata.com/react/queries.html#options-from-props

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a good case for a higher-order component that wraps the graphql call, and returns another function that accepts your lower-level component.  That HOC can then dynamically create a query based on the properties passed into it.

For example

```
export const graphqlWrapper = (...rest) => {
  const query = /* Create your query here. */;

  return graphql(query, ...rest);
}
```

Then use:

```
const ProfileWithData = graphqlWrapper({
  options: ({ avatarSize }) => ({ variables: { avatarSize } }),
})(Profile);
```

Or you can follow a similar pattern.

A little more detail on your use case would be useful, though.